# SSIS DATA Covertion task

Tags: ssis

Hi I am Trying to  use dataconvertion Transformation in ssis to get Execl data into a text file But The convertion Failed with The Fallowing Error

" [Data Conversion [77]] Error: The "output column "Copy of Description" (93)" failed because truncation occurred, and the truncation row disposition on "output column "Copy of Description" (93)" specifies failure on truncation. A truncation error occurred on the specified object of the specified component."

can any one help me to find out a solution

Answer (score 0):

Check this link:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/8c9c1d45-82d5-43bf-961b-a8e22dab221b/

Besides be aware that Excel uses the first 8 rows to determine the datatype ... This might cause some problems .

My advice is to save the Excel as CSV document and then use it.